# How can I modify default Magento Form Value?

Tags: magento-1.9, forms, adminform, values

I want to modify the value of the **Associate Website options** in

> Customer > Manage Customers > Add a New Customer.

The default value of Associate Website option is 'Admin' but I want to set to Main Website.

but I know that's a native Magento option so how can I rewrite it ?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you please describe in detail what actual you want?

Comment: I edited my post